# android - How to fit circle image in another circle image

Tags: android

I have a circle image(image1) and i am getting one more circle image(image2) dynamically. Now i want to fit the image2 in the image1. is it possible?if yes, How can we implement it.

**Image1**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to draw it within the bounds of the canvas of your image. Specifically you can grab the width/height of the second image and then change the drawing positioning of your bitmap by drawing it manually on a canvas and then controlling the X/Y offsetting during the drawing procedure.

### Something like this

[image]

This is if your source image is at a fixed resolution (ideal). The concept would be to build the image using the Canvas object and then superimpose the other image on top of it. And build a bitmap from that.